Trying to understand three-level (multi-level-ness) homotopy type theory as implemented by rzk (but may apply to any multilevel type theory)?
I am trying to move from Coq (which I can use a bit) to rzk https://rzk-lang.github.io/rzk/en/latest/ (for which I am reading articles referenced there and, of course, 2 HoTT standard textbooks). I still can not grasp the multi-level-ness or rzk? What it (multi-level-ness) encodes and why it is needed? And if we declare variable for some 3-level context, then is it the variable for the triplet (some kind of multiplication?) of all those 3 types from all those 3 levels (from respective universes)? And can there be variable of just one level (I see - yes)? And what is the difference between variable that is for 3 levels at once as opposite to variable of type of only one level?
I am reading also about HoTT applications to natural language semantics https://scholarworks.iu.edu/dspace/items/334f255d-7741-4748-a22e-af6b65a16ac4 because it can help to ground those abstract notions, but I don't see those level there.
There are ideas that univalent foundations can be used for giving alternative foundations of math, so - some example of translating Coq types into rzk would be helpful explanation for my question as it can demonstrate where cube and tope layers fit it. E.g. one usually starts Coq studies with the type of natural numbers and the rzk alternative is https://rzk-lang.github.io/rzk/en/v0.7.2/getting-started/dependent-types.rzk/#natural-numbers - without reference to cube or tope layers. Can we say that Coq types live in universe U and the homotopy things starts with addition of cube and tope layers and hence rzk is some generalization (but how?) of Coq? Btw, it seems to me that postulation is just shortcut (due to featurs in progress) and maybe the full definition of natural number (which will be implemented in the future) will involve also cube and tope layers and so - the perspective about the full definition (and obstacles to achieve it) may give some elucidation?
I find the practical formalization of Yoneda especially helpful https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.08340 (e.g. it gives comparisons with other formalisms as well), but still - I am not grasping the multi-levelness.
This my question is about the multi-level-ness or rzk and not about the background (which I am studying and of course, it would not be good to repeat is here, because so much good has been already written).

You can do HoTT in Coq just fine. Rzk is a language for synthetic $\infty$-category theory; essentially a directed version of HoTT.

Indeed, but I would like to do ∞-category theory (if synthetic, then even better) and, as I understand, Coq can do it for some specific models of ∞-categories but not for the synthetic version.

Anyway, I don't think you'll find many rzk experts on this website. I would advise you to ask on the rzk Zulip server.

It may be possible that multi-level-ness is more general approach which is widely known and which has sources quite apart from rzk, that is why rzk community doesn't explain it deeply. So, it may be possible that I should step back and read something like https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03307

Zulip is for the experts and developers.

Have you used Cubical before?

Thx, @IsAdisplayName, but I have already managed to solve my question. Types are types,but one is interested into tracking lower and higher order paths in them and this an be probed by shapes (e.g. intervals, triangles, horns) which ar functions Cube-Tope. I guess - Cubical does just the same tracking but shapes are defined by one layer (instead of two). Maybe I will manage to write answer myself. And thx for thesis, I am really interested in reading anything about fibrations (with aim to understand universes thoroughly).

In HoTT - the types are infinity-groupoid like. We have paths, paths between paths, and so on. Groupoids are just an instantiation of a category, so one might naturally wonder "what if the types are infinity categories"? That is, what if there was a morphism rather than a path, and we could have morphisms between morphisms, ad nauseum. This leads to and coincides with the study of something called directed homotopy type theory.
There are many routes to a directed type theory. You can add type formers for a morphism type and keep track of term variances yourself.
You can alternatively, in Agda, postulate a directed interval “2”, and talk about morphisms as functions out of “2” and so on. This is not nice, you would need to carry the endpoints as path data to talk about a morphisms type.
By using a layered type theory with shapes, you can get better behavior. Layers up top can be viewed as judgemental data in the type theory layer. This allows us to have a directed interval “2” and handle its logic in a higher layer, and have morphism types where the endpoint data is a judgement in the lower layer. This is what Riehl and Shulman do.
The first layer, the cube layer, is a simple type theory with products. The cubes give you variables that correspond to each axis. The layer built on top of that, the tope layer, allows you to talk about polytopes, shapes within the cube.  The shapes you can talk about are determined by your tope judgements. You can use both of these layers in the type theory layer.
The setting in which Rzk is implemented, in particular, works with a cube $\mathbb{2}$, and a tope layer that effectively makes the layer a coherent logic for the strict interval. The goal is to be able to construct cubes out of the directed interval, and talk about shapes such as prisms, triangles, and tetrahedra in the cube. The meets and join operations allow you to get intersections and unions of shapes. The equality operation allows you to talk about faces.
As I said earlier, the cube determines the variables and the rope judgements determine what shapes you can talk about. So naturally, cubical type theory can almost also be expressed as a type theory with shapes. All of this is explicated in sections 2 and 3 of "A type theory for synthetic $(\infty)$-categories".
